# condensing query using SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate, sql-order-by

I have a table with 4 things I want... the Name, Price, QTY, and a specific Date

There are lots of Entries per date:

```
Name          Price  Date

Twin Private  $25    06/02/09
Double        $35    06/02/09
Single        $20    06/02/09
Twin Private  $25    06/03/09
Double        $35    06/03/09
Single        $20    06/03/09
Twin Private  $25    06/04/09
Double        $35    06/04/09
Single        $20    06/04/09
```

How can I condense it into:

```
Name          Price_06/02/09  Price_06/03/09  Price_06/04/09

Twin Private  $25             $25             $30
Double        $35             $35             $50
Single        $20             $20             $40
```

Comment: My answer doesn't match your result because your expected result doesn't tie in with the input. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Garry Shutler: Result seems to be wrong in the question unless there is another variable that need to be accounted for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using something like this:

I'm using mysql, does it support PIVOT?

```
SELECT


    name, room_id,

      MAX(IF(to_days(bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-24') = 0, price, '')) AS Day1,
      MAX(IF(to_days(bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-24') = 1, price, '')) AS Day2,
      MAX(IF(to_days(bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-24') = 2, price, '')) AS Day3,
      MAX(IF(to_days(bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-24') = 3, price, '')) AS Day4,
      MAX(IF(to_days(bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-24') = 4, price, '')) AS Day5,
      MAX(IF(to_days(bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-24') = 5, price, '')) AS Day6,
      MAX(IF(to_days(bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-24') = 6, price, '')) AS Day7, spots
    FROM `availables`
    GROUP BY name
```

Comment: This is known as a "characteristic function"; see here: http://www.cs.newpaltz.edu/~pletcha/ADB/char_func.pdf

Answer (score 7):

I think this will do it:

```
select  Name,
        max(Price_06/02/09) as Price_06/02/09,
        max(Price_06/03/09) as Price_06/03/09,
        max(Price_06/04/09) as Price_06/04/09
from    (
        select    Name,
                  case Date
                      when '06/02/09' then Price
                      else null
                  end as Price_06/02/09,
                  case Date
                      when '06/03/09' then Price
                      else null
                  end as Price_06/03/09,
                  case Date
                      when '06/04/09' then Price
                      else null
                  end as Price_06/04/09
        from      Rates) as Aggregated
group by 
        Name
```

This works in two stages, the inner query stretches the data out so you'll end up with:

```
Name          Price_06/02/09  Price_06/03/09  Price_06/04/09

Twin Private  $25             null            null
Double        $35             null            null
Single        $20             null            null
Twin Private  null            $25             null
Double        null            $35             null
Single        null            $20             null
Twin Private  null            null            $25
Double        null            null            $35
Single        null            null            $20
```

Then the outer query groups by the name to flatten it to:

```
Name          Price_06/02/09  Price_06/03/09  Price_06/04/09

Twin Private  $25             $25             $25
Double        $35             $35             $35
Single        $20             $20             $20
```

Comment: If the date columns need to be dynamic then you could PIVOT

Comment: Unfortunately this query won't work if there are more than these three dates. Once I had to program query builder in similar case.

Comment: Pivot, especially in caps makes me think of friends http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_PklVas9cA

Comment: @Alexander yes, this is very fixed but the general concept can be applied to other situations.

Comment: PIVOT is also going to vary based on your database version. SQL Server 2005 has it, but 2000 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

To addition to Garry Shutler's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944198/condensing-query-using-sql/944211#944211) it could be useful to change columns and rows in places because there are definitely only limited quantity of room names but we can't say this about dates.